# How to check how many elements of boolean[] are true and what are their indices?

Tags: java, arrays

How one can check in the most elegant and fast fashion how many elements of `boolean[]` object are `true` and what are their indices? Say, one have:

```
boolean[] array = new boolean[] {false, false, true, true, false, false}
```

What is the best way to count `true` occurences and get its indices?

Comment: iterate over the array and count.

Comment: Do you have a slow and inefficient attempt to show us?

Comment: @YoungHobbit, Is there no other way than iteration?

Comment: Is there a problem with iteration? It's unclear to me what you're looking for at this point. (I don't believe there is.)

Comment: A totally different approach, but one that comes to mind whenever working with boolean arrays -- store all the booleans as bits in a `int`.  Then use `Integer.bitCount()`.

Comment: If your array is big enough you could split it in halves and take advantage of Instruction Parallelism (or even threads), ultimately leading to a O(log(n)) complexity.

Answer (score 4):

#### Nice and functional

Imperative style and avoiding boxing is certainly faster, but this is quite elegant:

```
List<Integer> list = 
IntStream.range(0, array.length)
         .filter(i -> array[i])
         .boxed()
         .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println("Indices : " + list);
System.out.println("Count   : " + list.size());
```

Yields

```
Indices : [2, 3]
Count   : 2
```

#### Old school using `BitSet`

Perhaps you should consider not using a `boolean[]`, but a `BitSet` in the first place:

```
BitSet bits = new BitSet(array.length);
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    if (array[i])
        bits.set(i);

System.out.println("Indices : " + bits);
System.out.println("Count   : " + bits.cardinality());
```

Yields

```
Indices : {2, 3}
Count   : 2
```

Answer (score -1):

This could be one possible way.

```
    Boolean[] array = new Boolean[] { false, false, true, true, false, false };
    List<Boolean> arrayList = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
    arrayList.addAll(Arrays.asList(array));
    System.out.println(Collections.frequency(arrayList, true));
```

Collections have lot of utility functions to take advantage of.